# How can I style a single letter or word in a sentence drawn with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

It seems there's no out-of-the-box way to do this (I've skimmed the docs), but just in case: if I want to draw a sentence to an image with PIL but want control over individual words (or even individual letters), how can I do that?

I'm also open to solutions that use a library other than PIL.

The image below shows the kind of effect I'm going for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a direct way to do this. However, you are able to determine the text size - http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.textsize.

You could draw the first part of your text, get the size of that text to calculate the new position for the next part of text, and so on. That way, you could style each part of the text in any matter you see fit.